# JS code fires on page load instead of waiting for click event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having difficulty with this code. I'm trying to get the JS to execute on a click event however, it is executing when the page loads and also when the user clicks. Any help is much appreciated!

```
<body>
<a href="" id="calc">click me!</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById('calc').onclick=xfx()
}

xfx = function (){
alert("x");
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `xfx()` should be `xfx`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are invoking the function instead of assigning it to the on click event

This should do it:

```
document.getElementById('calc').onclick = xfx;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going insane on that one.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
    document.getElementById('calc').onclick = xfx();
```

means that you want to assign the onclick to the *results* of the xfx() call.

You probably want

```
    document.getElementById('calc').onclick = xfx;
```

which means that you want to assign to onlick the xfx function itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking it over!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use addEventListener to look for the click on your variable; like so:

```
var clickMe = document.getElementById('calc');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', function () {
alert("hello!");
});
```

Where your variable is clickMe, defining the id 'calc', and when clicked it triggers the alert.

Here's the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/89Nvb/

Answer (score -2):

Should be

```
function xfx() {
  alert("x");
}
```

Comment: @myp it is a part of the problem.

Comment: it makes sense. I wrote it poorly.